PySide6 QColorDialog Inner Layout Size
Whenever I open the QColorDialog, the values in spinbuttons (Right Bottom) are not shown properly.


Python version : 3.12.4

PySide6 Version : 6.7.2


[ Test Code ]
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLayout, QWidget, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QColorDialog
from PySide6.QtGui import QColor 
import sys

class myWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        layout = QGridLayout()
        
        self.button = QPushButton("Color")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.set_button_color)
        
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        
        self.setLayout(layout)
        
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")
        self.show()
        
    def set_button_color(self):
        dialog = QColorDialog()
        dialog.setSizeGripEnabled(True)
        dialog.layout().setSizeConstraint(QLayout.SetNoConstraint)
        
        color = dialog.getColor()
        
        if QColor.isValid(color):
            print("Selected Color Information:", color.name())
            self.button.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s;"%color.name())

app = QApplication.instance()
if not app:
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
myApp = myWidget()
sys.exit(app.exec())


Yet another 6.7 issue, already reported as QTBUG-124118 but actually caused by the new Windows11Style and also reported as QTBUG-124150. It should be actually fixed starting from 6.7.3 (even though the latter says it should work since 6.7.2), which is going to be released in a few days.

Note: getColor() is a static function that creates a new QColorDialog based on its arguments, so creating a QColorDialog and trying to set any of its parameters is completely useless if you then use such a function, as the dialog would only be used as a reference to access the method of the class. No instance will ever be considered with that usage. This means that the only way of working around this for <6.7.3 with non native dialog is by using the QColorDialog instance exec()/open() after setting another QStyle for all spin boxes.

@musicamante OK Much appreciated!
